# How can I evaluate the normed cumulative distribution transform explicitly?

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, optimal-transport

Given measures $\mu_0, \mu_1$ on $X,Y \subset \mathbb R$ with densitites $f_0:X\to \mathbb R $ and $f_1:Y \to \mathbb R$ and a measurable map $T:X \to Y$ that pushes $\mu_0$ onto $\mu_1$ such that
$$\int_{T^{-1}(A)}d\mu_0=\int_Ad\mu_1 \quad$$ for any Lebesgue-measurable $A \subset Y$.
Through Lebesgue integration we get
$$\int_{\inf X}^x f_0(\tau)d\tau=\int_{\inf Y}^{T(x)} f_1(\tau)d\tau. \quad (*)$$ One can then define the Cumulative Distribution Transform (CDT) of $f_1$ w.r.t the reference $f_0$ which we denote by $\hat{f_1}:X \to \mathbb R$ given by
$$\hat{f_1}(x)=(T(x)-x)\sqrt{f_0(x)} \quad (**)$$ where $T$ satisfies $(*).$

I now want to compute the CDT in the $L_2$-norm explicitly for the example $X=[0,1], Y=\mathbb R$ and $f_0(x)=1$ and $f_1(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$.

So in order to compute the CDT, we need to solve for $T:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ by plugging into $(*)$:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{T(x)}f_1(\tau)d\tau =\int_{-\infty}^{T(x)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{\tau^2}{2}} d\tau = \int_0^1 1 d\tau = x.$$
By setting $\phi(x):=\int_{-\infty}^{x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{\tau^2}{2}} d\tau$ we can formulate it as $$\phi(T(x))=x$$ where $\phi$ is monotonically increasing with an existing inverse, hence $T(x)=\phi^{-1}(x)$. Finally plugging it into $(**)$ yields
$$\hat{f_1}(x)=(T(x)-x)\sqrt{f_0(x)}=\phi^{-1}(x)-x.$$

My question now is, how can I compute
$$\Vert\hat{f_1}\Vert_{L^2}^2=\int_0^1(\phi^{-1}(x)-x)^2 dx?$$ I am on the one hand unsure how to take the inverse of $\phi$ and also wouldn't know how to then evaluate the integral. Any online tools for that?

Comment: Looks to me like the entity you compute is nothing but the Wasserstein distance between uniform and Gaussian, for which I would not expect a closed analytical form.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Tobsn seems correct. There are known results for the inverse of error function (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseErf.html), but I don't know about the OT cost between a Gaussian and uniform distribution. There is also python code for numerically approximating the CDT, and hence its norm, numerically in Python: https://github.com/rohdelab/PyTransKit